# delete records from multiple linked tables access vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have 100 linked tables in ms-Access with the Name "TBL*"
and they have the same columns. I tried to create a module using vba that deletes some rows according to an sql query as follows:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteRecords()

    Dim strSQL As String 'sql statement
    Dim db As DAO.Database
   Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
   Set db = CurrentDb
   
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    DoCmd.SetWarnings False
    If Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*") And tdf.Name Like "TBL*" Then
       db.Execute "DELETE  FROM " & tdf.Name & " WHERE " & tdf.Fields(2) & " NOT LIKE '%MUST NOT DEL%'", dbFailOnError
     End If
    'DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    DoCmd.SetWarnings True
   Next
End Sub
```

Which means I need only the rows that their second column is like '%MUST NOT DEL%' and delete the others. This code gives me an error of invalid operation. I tried a lot of changes but nothing. I think that maybe I have a syntax error on my query. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: I suggest you generate the `DELETE FROM...` SQL in a string variable first so you can see the completed statement (and check it for errors/issues), and _then_ pass it to `db.Execute`.

Comment: @HansUp Worse, likely all rows are deleted, since it's `NOT LIKE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *"Invalid operation"* error happens because the code references just `tdf.Fields(2)` where you want to include the field name in your SQL statement.  That error should go away if you explicitly ask for the field's name: `tdf.Fields(2).Name`

However, you mentioned the *"second column"* is the one which may contain text matching `'%MUST NOT DEL%'`.  And, since the `Fields` collection is zero-based, you need `Fields(1).Name` instead of `Fields(2).Name`

There is another potential problem lurking.  When executing a query from `CurrentDb`, Access expects `*` instead of `%` as the wild card unless you have set the Access option for *"SQL Server Compatible Syntax (ANSI 92)"*.  Since I don't know which case applies to you, I used `ALIKE` instead of `LIKE` ... which signals the db engine to expect the ANSI 92 `%` wildcard.

Test the `WHERE` clause with a `SELECT` query to make sure it targets only the rows you later want to delete.

```vb
For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
    If tdf.Name Like "TBL*" Then
        strSQL =  "DELETE  FROM [" & tdf.Name & "] WHERE [" & tdf.Fields(1).Name & "] NOT ALIKE '%MUST NOT DEL%'"
        Debug.Print strSQL ' you can inspect the completed statement in the Immediate window;
                           ' Ctrl + g will take you there
        db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
      End If
Next
```

Notes:

1. Since you're not using `DoCmd.RunSQL` to run your query, I don't think you need `DoCmd.SetWarnings False` here.
2. Whenever `tdf.Name Like "TBL*"` is True, `Not (tdf.Name Like "MSys*")` must also be True.  So you don't need both for your `If ... Then` condition; `Like "TBL*"` is sufficient.
3. I bracketed the table and field names to avoid problems if either of those names include spaces, punctuation, or match the names of functions or keywords.